# How can I access themeprovider/styled-components styles from render in React/NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I have my code setup working like this....

_app.js

```
<ThemeProvider theme={clientGroupTheme}>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <Layout>
      <Component {...this.props} />
    </Layout>
</ThemeProvider>
```

someComponent.js

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'
export const LoginMenuStyles = createGlobalStyle`
    .exampleClass {
         color:${(props) => props.theme.secondaryColor};
    }`

class LoginMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <>
                <div className="exampleClass">Test</div>
                <PassColorComponent myColor={${(props) => props.theme.secondaryColor}} /> //This
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Basically I want to pass that same color value as a prop (//This). It works fine in the styled-component class but I can get it to work in the render method and pass to that component.
Is it possible? am I close?
Thanks

Comment: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced  Maybe the section "Getting the theme without sytled components" will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 'withTheme' higher-order component is what you are looking for.

```
import { withTheme } from 'styled-components'


class LoginMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <>
                <div className="exampleClass">Test</div>
                <PassColorComponent myColor={this.props.theme.secondaryColor} />
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default withTheme(LoginMenu);
```

don't forget to wrap the component at export inside the withTheme component (see bottom line). That's how the styled theme props will be passed to LoginMenu component.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it with a functionalcomponent like this: export default function LoginMenu (props) {

Comment: @Thomas Byy

`import {withTheme} from 'styled-components';`

`function Component(props){`

  `console.log(props.theme)`
  `// component structure here`
`}`

`export default withTheme(Component)`

Answer (score 0):

The theme is available only within `styled` function when creating a *styled component*. If you want to access in *React component*, you could e.g. directly pass the *theme* down as a prop.

```
<Component {...this.props} theme={clientGroupTheme} />
```

Then, you will be able to access the *theme* object.

```
<PassColorComponent myColor={props.theme.secondaryColor} />
```